# How to require users to login when not logged in

Tags: plugins, themes

I am trying to develop my first WordPress site, its going to be a school site, I develop sites normally, but this is my first time of using a CMS to do that.

The school site is supposed to display the homepage of the school when users view the site, but then, it is supposed to also show a `login link` to users when they are not logged in, and if they are logged in, it is supposed to show extra items on the menu bar.

I do not see how to achieve this without some conditional statements in place, but I really hope there is a way to get there without coding, I am new to wordpress and I have not really gone deep into knowing much of its classes and functions, so most preferable I would like to achieve this without coding using plugins or maybe specific themes (if possible), and if not, I would still like to know how to go about it.

I hope my question is not too ambiguous. I would really appreciate all answers. Thanks...

Comment: Asking for plugin/theme recommendation is out of the scope here. So Please check http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask and http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can check if the user is logged in or not by using the `conditional statement` **is_user_logged_in** http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in

Comment: In the add/edit page/post screens you will see a link to make the page or post public or private. Marking it private will show the link but require a password as you described.

Comment: Yes that is how you make a post private or password protected.

Can you please make your head straight and ask for one question at a  time and for another question, add another in WPSE

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure if this will be much help, but I have done similar using a plugin called [Theme My Login](http://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/), this allows for login and log out links in the menu.

I have then used WPMUDEV's [membership](http://wordpress.org/plugins/membership/) plugin to register users and to show two different menu's depending on whether the user is a guest or a registered member.

If you keep the home page sparse with a Call To Action to register, then your user is likely to register and follow that funnel.

I hope that helps.